Dynamic copy function
I have a function with a dynamic copy statement and when I try to SELECT function, I get the error "query has no destination for result data"
select loadTodaysData();

CREATE FUNCTION loadTodaysData()
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) AS $$
DECLARE vtoday VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'COPY nsn 
        FROM ''C:\Users\yuju\SQL_Data\test_''|| vtoday || ''.csv'' 
        with delimiter ','
        csv header';
END; $$
language plpgsql;

I want this to update my table everyday automatically from a folder. Function was created without an error.

Sorry code isn't formatted well in this post

A plain syntax problem. You didn't double all the single quotes in the statement string.

Your stored function does not return a value, so you have nothing to select. Either return a value, like returning vtoday from your stored function and then you will have something to select, or, if you just want to execute your command, then refactor your function into a stored procedure and then use the CALL statement like
CALL loadTodaysData();


RETURN vtoday after the EXECUTE statement?

@YujuTakahashi yes...

Thanks for the reply, I am still getting the same error message
